# How to add Rounded top Corners to Bar by using react-chartjs-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-chartjs

I'm using react-chartjs-2 for building bar on site.
https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2

I have done my home work there is no proper documentation on 'option' object.

please refer to this sandbox link for CODE I have written. https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-mountain-3eh2c

````
import "./styles.css";

import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

export default function App() {
  const dataOnBar = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    dataOnBar.push(i);
  }

  console.log('dataonBar',dataOnBar)

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: { enabled: false },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: false
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          display: false,
          ticks: {
            min: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  let barData = {
    labels: dataOnBar.map((val, i) => i),
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "blue",
        data: dataOnBar
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Bar data={barData} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0dzp3jxw/

Comment: Thank you for responding. It's not what I looking for solution of this.  https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-mountain-3eh2c

Comment: No problem, your sandbox isn't working at my end. So from question heading I assumed this might be helpful.

Comment: It's working ! I have tried with different machines !